# how to parse a binary encoded rss feed

Tags: python, rss, urllib2, binary-data

hi i am having a problem downloading and reading in a rss feed from a particular site, the issue seems to be that the resulting downloaded rss feed looks to be in binary format, can anybody tell me how i can get this back into a readable format that i can then send to beautiful soup for parsing?.

here is my code so far:-

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

rss_feed = urllib2.urlopen("http://kat.ph/usearch/ubuntu/?rss=1", timeout=5.0).read()
print rss_feed #will display binary not expected xml
rss_feed_soup = BeautifulSoup(rss_feed)
```

so just to clarify i cannot seem to get the resulting xml when trying to read using urllib2, if i view the rss feed in any modern web browser the rss is displayed correctly, what am i missing here? , is the rss feed binary encoded and if so how do i correctly decode it?.

thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feed is gzipped by the server for efficient downloading; it has a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header set.

Use [`feedparser`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser/) to download and parse it instead of using `urllib2` and BeautifulSoup.

If you have to use `urllib2`, also use the `gzip` module to decompress the content first:

```
import gzip
from cStringIO import StringIO

rss_feed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(rss_feed)).read()
```

Comment: thanks very much for your quick reply, i will take a look at this first thing tomorrow morning and report back.